# Can I assume PHP's time() and MySQL's NOW() will be the same?

Tags: php, mysql, time, crud

I am creating an instance of an object and using an INSERT query on a MySQL database at the same time. The table in the database has a field called `modified`, which is automatically updated whenever the row is inserted/changed.

When the constructor of my class is called, it sets the properties of the object to be those used in the query. My question is, do I have to run a `SELECT` query on my newly inserted/updated row to obtain its timestamp, or can I safely assume that PHP's `time()` function would return the same value?

For example:

```
<?php
// Inside the __construct method of a class
static::query('
   INSERT INTO `table` (
      `name`,
      `content`
   )
   VALUES
      (
         "name",
         "content"
      );
');
   // During insertion, `modified` column is set to NOW()
$this->name = 'name';
$this->content = 'content';
$this->modified = time();
   // Can I count on this being reflected properly?
?>
```

There are only two possibilities I can think of that would negate this: (1) the database is on a server with a different local time; (2) time passes between the query and the call of the `time()` function (which I seriously doubt would even make a difference of 1 second...).

Is it worth the expense of a `SELECT` query to get the updated time, or should I stick with calling the `time()` function and risk that the next time the row is selected, the `modified` value might be different than when it was instantiated, in my application?

Comment: assume nothing, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

PHP and MySQL can be running on two different servers, and even if they are running on the same server the timezone could be miconfigured for one or the other or both. Pick a single time source, either PHP or MySQL, and then use it exclusively.

Also, many hosting companies either don't know or don't care enough about their clocks to know that they tend to float without properly configuring ntpd. Some servers float a few seconds per week, others float a few minutes per day.

Comment: Okay. I guess my automatic thinking was to use the SELECT query, but now I'm thinking I might actually prefer to use PHP's `time()` and insert it, because I also store some files only using the filesystem and `filemtime()` and then I would be using the same clock for both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same since the server's times may be different (maybe just some msec but maybe a whole timezone) and there are always (small but existent) delays in processing.

Use SELECT.